How to include "mqueue.h" in msys2 environment?
I'm trying to compile a project with msys2 for Windows, the project is originally for linux and it has a line:
#include <mqueue.h>

In my msys2 environment, there is a file of C:\msys64\usr\include\mqueue.h, in my understanding, it's MSYS environment.
But I'd like to compile it using ucrt64 environment (I'm not sure if it's correct of not, but that's my current understanding.)
In ucrt64, the header file should be in the folder of C:\msys64\ucrt64\include, I assume, but I can't find the file there.
So my question is: how can I found the file of "mqueue.h" in ucrt64 environment?
or should I use the msys environment instead?

I would like to take pthread.h as another example:
pthread.h is avaible at both C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\pthread.h and C:\msys64\usr\include\pthread.h, so use it in ucrt64 is possible.
